# Esconder uma coluna de um WebGrid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Boa tarde.

Tenho um WebGrid e gostaria de deixar uma coluna invisível. Como poderia fazer isso?

esse é o grid:

```
@{
Layout = null;
WebGrid grid = new WebGrid(Model);
}


@grid.GetHtml(columns: new [] {
grid.Column("ID_PARAMETER"),
grid.Column("CD_PARAMETER"),
grid.Column("TP_PARAMETER"),
grid.Column("DS_CONTENT"),
grid.Column("DT_UPDATE"),
grid.Column("Edit", format: @<text> @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "EDITMOBILEDATA", 
new{id = item.ID_PARAMETER})</text>),
grid.Column("Delete", format: @<text> @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "DELETEMOBILEDATA",
new {id = item.ID_PARAMETER})</text>)
})
```

Gostaria de esconder a coluna ID_PARAMETER.

Comment: Seria este aqui WebGrid grid = new WebGrid(Model);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nunca usei este componente, mas existe um construtor que pode ser usado assim:

```
WebGrid obj = new WebGrid(Model, columnNames: new[] { "ID_PARAMETER", "CD_PARAMETER", "DS_CONTENT", "DT_UPDATE" });
```

[A referência está aqui](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.webgrid.webgrid%28v=vs.111%29.aspx).

---

**EDIT**

Aparentemente não basta especificar o nome da coluna. É preciso definir seu formato de forma manual:

```
grid.Column("TP_PARAMETER", format: @<input type="hidden" name="TP_PARAMETER" value="@item.TP_PARAMETER"/>),
```

Comment: esse mesmo que estou usando, esqueci de mencionar na pergunta. Teria como esconder uma coluna dele?

Comment: Então, eu tirei a coluna no construtor. Veja se funciona, por favor.

Comment: Testei aqui, continua mostrando a coluna do ID

Comment: @PauloHenrique Atualizei a resposta.

Comment: Com esse format funcionou. Muito obrigado