# Ocultar dinâmicamente uma coluna de um WebGrid

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, webgrid

Como posso ocultar em tempo de execução uma coluna do **WebGrid** ?
Por exemplo, quero ocultar a coluna `Parametro`, seria algo assim:

```
    grid.Column("Empresa", "Empresa"),
if(item.valor1 == X){
    grid.Column("Parametro", "Parametro"),
}
     grid.Column("Data", format: @<text>@item.DataInclusao.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")</text>),
```

Neste post: [Esconder uma coluna de um WebGrid](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/64523/esconder-uma-coluna-de-um-webgrid) mostra como ocultar mas não em tempo de execução.

Answer (score 0):

Encontrei a solução que funcionou para o meu cenário:

```
var gridColumns = new List<WebGridColumn>();

    if (Model.Empresa != null)
    {
        gridColumns.Add(grid.Column("Empresa", "Empresa"));
    };

   @grid.GetHtml(
tableStyle: "grid",
headerStyle: "head",
columns: grid.Columns(
gridColumns.ToArray()));
```